# Current Date as default in ACCEPT sql*plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to make a report script that will very likely be used on the spot. So I want the accept to default to the current date, but I either get 'current_date' as text, or the user input as numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> col today new_value today

SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') as today from dual;

TODAY
----------
2018-04-23

1 row selected.

SQL> def today
DEFINE TODAY           = "2018-04-23" (CHAR)

SQL> accept dt date format YYYY-MM-DD default &today prompt "Enter a date (press ENTER for today's date): "
Enter a date (press ENTER for today's date):

SQL> def dt
DEFINE DT              = "2018-04-23" (CHAR)
```

In a script you can hide the details with `set termout off` at the start and `set termout on` just before the `accept` prompt.

I like to use `YYYY-MM-DD` for this because then queries can simply use it with:

```
select blah from blahblah
where  sale_date = date '&dt'
```

Comment: what does that first line do?